# Spring Boot + Testcontainers with remote liquidbase migrations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testcontainers

I have two Spring boot applications that don't know about Liquidbase migrations since migrations are stored in a separate repository and applied by Jenkins.

I want to introduce Testcontainers testing to test communication with DB.
The issue is that I cannot store these migrations locally in the services to avoid duplication.

Is there any way to pull migrations before TestContainer start? Maybe some workaround?

Comment: How would your application pull and apply the migrations for production? Can't you replicate the mechanism for your tests? This issue seems independent of the use of Testcontainers.

Comment: @KevinWittek migrations will be pulled for productions using Jenkins and its plugin

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I decided to use JGit SDK to download migrations.

More information about JGit here:
https://www.baeldung.com/jgit